# Change PouchDB's rev algorithm to use a blockchain / hashchain pattern

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, blockchain

Is it within reason to change CouchDB / PouchDB's revision algorithm 'under the hood' to use a blockchain style 'hashchain' such that the _rev of every doc is the result of a hash of it's previous revisions?

Such a model would help preserve the integrity of revisions; in a distributed network for example it could essentially be the basis of an immutable history for your entire db.

Comment: Something along the lines of secure-scuttlebutt https://github.com/ssbc/secure-scuttlebutt but implemented / integrated with PouchDB API

Comment: Here's a good primer/refresh on the concept of a blockchain or 'hashchain' which should clearly demonstrate the new _rev model I am suggesting https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_160oMzblY8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the _rev **is** a deterministic hash over the document and all of its revisions, at least for CouchDB. It's also using the previous _rev, so you basically get a deterministic hash if you make the same sequence of updates to a document.

Unfortunately, it's an MD5 hash, so it isn't really suitable for security-related stuff.

AFAIK, the actual value of the _rev is never checked, only the part before the dash must be numeric. So you *could* write a PouchDB plugin that changes the _rev generation and also checks the integrity of the _rev value on every update.

Comment: Awesome great, that clarifies things.  And 'deterministic hash' - yes, maybe more accurate than 'hashchain' thank-you. 

The broader goal is a more or less a Couch/PouchDB API for a distributed blockchain.  So I am looking at, alternative to a plugin - perhaps an 'adapter' to mount PouchDB's API on something like secure-scuttlebut; here's an GH issue I opened proposing the idea.  https://github.com/ssbc/secure-scuttlebutt/issues/189

Yet dominictarr makes the point it is better to use the strength of both (preferring one or the other depending on use case)!  So I agree with him there.

Comment: Note that this is only true for CouchDB, For PouchDB, the `_rev` is random. Although [there is talk](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/4642) of changing that.